# use react render a nested object in jsx

Tags: reactjs, nested-object

I am trying to render a nested object from a firestore database in react jsx with the map function. The 'text' property like 'I will save document" is contained within what appears to be an object(document) that contains an array[blocks] that contains another array[inlineStyleRanges] that contains an object (text). I am trying to render the text object and I am having a hard time figuring out the syntax to make it render correctly.

**The object has this structure:**

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, suspendisse velit"
document:
blocks: Array(1)
0:
 data: {}
 depth: 0
 entityRanges: []
 inlineStyleRanges: []
 key: "8u7m4"
 text: "I will save this document."
 type: "unstyled"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
entityMap: {}
__proto__: Object
id: Timestamp {seconds: 1551856294, nanoseconds: 879000000}
title: "TCC/NIBF SUMMARY SHEET"
__proto__: Object
```

**my attempted render method looks like this:**

```
render() {
  const urlID = this.state.urlID;
  const results = this.state.documents;
  const postList = results.map((result, index) => {
    if (urlID === result.id.seconds.toString()) {
      return (
        <Card key={result.id.seconds}>
          <CardBody>
            <CardTitle>File Name: {result.title}</CardTitle>
            <CardText>File Description: {result.description}</CardText>
            {/*<CardText>File Document Text: {result.document... }</CardText>*/}
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });
  return <div>{postList}</div>;
}
```

Comment: So what's going wrong ?

Comment: everything is okay with the code I have shown except the code I commented out: {/*<CardText>File Document Text: {result.document... }</CardText>*/}. I am trying to render the 'text' property that is in the inlineStyleRanges. So, I am in a multi dimensional array and nested object using the map function. Every time I try to render the text property I get an error saying text is 'undefined,' leading me to believe my syntax is off somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I used the new es6 Map function to make a new object map that I turned into an array using the spread operator and then looked at the structure of the object as an array in chrome dev tools.

After studying it, I found the correct syntax:

```
<CardText>File text: {result.document.blocks["0"].text}</CardText>
```